# Is there a blueprint to developing 3d iOS games such as Subway Surfers?

Tags: ios, game-engine

I apologise in advance for my ignorance :)

I'm a n00b to iOS development, but have experience in Ruby. I really want to learn how to develop games such as endless runners and 3d games in general such as Subway surfers.

So far from my research i've gathered that I will need to learn objective-C and learn how to operate Unity3d. As there is so much conflicting information out there i'm struggling to establish where to start as i do not wish to waste time.

So if someone could create a linear list of steps that i could take to start my game development journey I would be ever so grateful.

Thank you. JB.

Answer (score 2):

you can create games through the **unity 3d**. it does not requires learn objective C language. if you are already familiar with the C# then it is enough for this. unity 3D requires scripting.it is cross platform engine

**Antiryad Gx** :it is another one game engine.it also does not requires objective C. if you are already familiar with c, C++ then it is enough for create 3d for ios. it is cross platform engine.
BatteryTech SDK:based on c++.

**Cocos3d**: it is sophisticated 3D application development framework for the iOS platform. With cocos3d, you can build sophisticated, dynamic 3D games and applications using Objective-C.

[visit this link](http://mobilegameengines.com/iphone/3d_game_engines), it has list of game engines in which you can check for the language you are familiar. by this way ,you can save time of learnng new language& directly concentrate on game development